# Image displaying in Layout blade but not inside @content, in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**Here is my code for Layout Blade**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/aos.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">

    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="partners">
                        <img src="imgs/logo_footer.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        <img src="imgs/logo_footer2.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:35px;">
                        <img src="imgs/logo_footer3.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it works fine.
With result "imgs/logo_footer.png"

But in the content, using the same way, the result is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/imgs/beatriz02062020.png"

I tryed with asset().

Comment: Give a slash (`/`) in the begin of src `src="/imgs/logo_footer.png"`

Comment: You'll really need to use the url builder of your choice. Cause at the moment you'll deploy your app online there's a big chance that all url beginning with "/" will point to "/" folder of the unix server it'll be deployed on.

Comment: Thank you all, in the end all answers worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to `dd(asset($pathToYourImage));` somewhere in the view to be sure of the path. Than comment below to show me the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line for displaying image:

```
 <img src="{{URL::to('/').'/imgs/logo_footer.png'}}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

for regular images in public folder like `public/assets/images/img.png` you can try

```
<img src="{{url('assets/images/img.png')}}">
```

or

```
<img src="{{assets('assets/images/img.png')}}">
```

also if you online you should consider change `APP_URL` in your `.env` file
as `url()` or `assets()` get the `APP_URL` value and use it in url

do not forget to run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

after any change in online version of `.env` file

**if your image is uploaded image form a form read the these down.**

the point is that the upload path is relevant to storage folder in your laravel project. so if you do every thing by the book, you should try the following,
first thing check files in `storage/app/public folder` , you should found your files there
also check your settings in `config/filesystem.php` in your project.

if you found the files in `storage/app/public/{any-folder-name}`
and the project configuration in config/filesystem.php is public
do the following
run command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

this will make a symlink (a shortcut)

then use this piece of code to get your images

```
Storage::url($image_path)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer really worked and helped me.

Comment: @BraianMendes thanks for comment , happy to hear that, please vote up my answer if my answer where helpful